# SQLAlchemy and Oracle - How to get VARCHAR2 columns to use BYTE and not CHAR?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

It looks like SQLAlchemy defaults to creating `VARCHAR2` columns as `CHAR`. How can I have it create with `BYTE` instead?

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    name = Column(String(10), primary_key=True)

Foo.__table__.create(bind=engine)
```

This creates the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE XXMD.FOO
(
  NAME  VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)                       NOT NULL
)
```

Instead, I would like it to create the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE XXMD.FOO
(
  NAME  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)                       NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why? That'd seem like a source of confusion since `String(10)` is a generic type that maps Python strings of max length 10 to SQL using the most suitable DB type.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I have another system I'm integrating with that unfortunately uses `BYTE` instead of `CHAR`. Moreover, `BYTE` is the default type used in Oracle if it wasn't specified, so I would think that `SQLAlchemy` would support it.

Comment: Looking at how the Oracle dialect handles varchar, there's no way to explicitly define BYTE: https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/base.py#L592, barring you create your own SQLA type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Mike Bayer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sqlalchemy/VARCHAR2$20BYTE$20CHAR%7Csort:relevance/sqlalchemy/W0vCOS0aM6w/qTaEQzwBAwAJ):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles


class VARCHAR2Byte(String):
    pass


@compiles(VARCHAR2Byte)
def compile_varchar2_byte(type_, compiler, **kw):
    len = type_.length
    return 'VARCHAR2(%i BYTE)' % len
```